# replacing strings in a document and undo

Tags: google-apps-script

In a mailMerge script I'm working on I use `.replaceText()` to replace fields with their corresponding values in a database.

The interface allows to test in the document to see if the result is looking as expected and I need to have a 'UNDO' function to get my fields in their original position so that I can use it with other values.(this script is bounded to a document in a side bar, see [this post for illustration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799734/is-there-a-way-to-remove-a-script-from-a-doc-using-the-new-doc-embedded-script))

The script below does that pretty well by keeping in memory the field names an their replacement values.
The only detail that bothers me is that I had to define a special "empty" label for fields that have no values in the current test data to prevent losing their track in the document.
(I used a numbered identifier like °vide12°).

This is working perfectly but it's not ideal since the document in test mode is not exactly a representation of the final document because of these °videXX° that I use...

The question is  : does anyone have a better idea or another approach to "localize" the  replacement data when there is no data in a less visible way ? (I know this sound weird... that's why I explain the whole situation :-)

Considering the way Google Docs are build I thought that I could get the complete element structure and rebuild the doc from that info but I'm afraid it won't be possible since the smallest element is a paragraph and fields are mainly just single words...

Here is the relevant part of the code I use, I added a few comments to make it (hopefully) clear.

```
function valuesInDoc(e){ // this function replaces the fields with database values
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 
  var listVal = UserProperties.getProperty('listSel').split(',');
  var replacements = [];
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var find = body.findText('#ch');
  if(find == null){var ui = DocumentApp.getUi() ; ui.alert("Aucun champ (#chX#) trouvé dans le document... Veuillez insérer des identifiants aux endroits souhaités");return app};
  var curData =   UserProperties.getProperty('selItem').split('|');
  var Headers = [];
  var OriHeaders = UserProperties.getProperty('Headers').split('|');
  for(n=0;n<OriHeaders.length;++n){
    Headers.push('#'+OriHeaders[n]+'#');
  }
  var fctSpe = 0 ;
  for(var i in Headers){if(Headers[i].indexOf('SS')>-1){fctSpe = i}}
  for(var n=0;n<listVal.length;++n){
    var realIdx = Number(listVal[n]);
    var newField = ChampSpecial(curData,realIdx,fctSpe);
    if(newField!=''){replacements.push(newField+'∏'+'#ch'+(n+1)+'#')};
    //Logger.log('value in '+n+'='+realIdx+'  >>  '+Headers[realIdx]+'  =  '+ChampSpecial(curData,realIdx,fctSpe))
    app.getElementById('textField'+(n+1)).setHTML(ChampSpecial(curData,realIdx,fctSpe));
    if(e.parameter.source!='dataSelection'){
    body.replaceText('#ch'+(n+1)+'#',newField);
    }
  }
  UserProperties.setProperty('replacements',replacements.join('|'));// memorize the replacement pattern
  cloakOn();// hide hidden fields
  return app;
}



function fieldsInDoc(e){ // this function does the reverse process and restores the field identifiers
  cloakOff();// show hidden fields
  var replacements = UserProperties.getProperty('replacements').split('|');
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  for(var n=0;n<replacements.length;++n){
    var field = replacements[n].split('∏')[1];
    var testVal = replacements[n].split('∏')[0];    
    body.replaceText(testVal,field);
    }
}

function ChampSpecial(curData,idx,ref){ // this function handles a special case for a specific field, the relevant part is right below, see comment
  if(idx==-1){return''};
  if(curData[idx-1]==''){return'°vide'+idx+'°'};// this is the "empty" identifier
  if(idx<ref){return curData[idx]};
  if(idx>ref){return curData[idx-1]}
  var firstSpace = curData[idx-1].indexOf(' ');
  var apos = curData[idx-1].indexOf("'");
//Logger.log('firstSpace='+firstSpace+'  apos='+apos)
  if(firstSpace<4&&firstSpace>-1){return curData[idx-1].substring(firstSpace+1)};
  if(apos<3&&apos>-1){return curData[idx-1].substring(apos+1)};
  return curData[idx-1];
}
```

---

**EDIT :**  thanks to Mogsdad's brilliant answer I wrote these 2 functions to hide/show the unused fields. Sinc in my case I use °XX° (XX=2 digit number) to keep track of the unused fields I had to modify his code to look for this particular string and used 2 loops to get all the fields.

I call these function from the menu AND from the two other functions that handle the replacement (I updated the code above as well)

It might appear a waste of time since I iterate more that 100 times but the result is instantaneous... so why bother ?
here is the code in case it gives someone an idea.

```
function cloakOn() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var found = [];
  for(var n=1;n<23;++n){
    for(var f=0;f<5;++f){
      if(f==0){found[f] = body.findText('°'+Utilities.formatString("%02d",n)+'°')}else{found[f] = body.findText('°'+Utilities.formatString("%02d",n)+'°',found[f-1])}
      if(found[f]!=null){
        var elemTxt = found[f].getElement().asText();
        elemTxt.setFontSize(found[f].getStartOffset(), found[f].getEndOffsetInclusive(),0)
        var background = elemTxt.getBackgroundColor(found[f].getStartOffset()) || "#ffffff";
        elemTxt.setForegroundColor(found[f].getStartOffset(), found[f].getEndOffsetInclusive(), background);
      }
    }
  }
}

function cloakOff() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var found = [];
  for(var n=1;n<23;++n){
    for(var f=0;f<5;++f){
      if(f==0){found[f] = body.findText('°'+Utilities.formatString("%02d",n)+'°')}else{found[f] = body.findText('°'+Utilities.formatString("%02d",n)+'°',found[f-1])}
      if(found[f]!=null){
        var elemTxt = found[f].getElement().asText();
        var size = elemTxt.getParent().getFontSize();
        elemTxt.setFontSize(found[f].getStartOffset(), found[f].getEndOffsetInclusive(),size)
        var background = elemTxt.getBackgroundColor(found[f].getStartOffset()) || "#000000";
        elemTxt.setForegroundColor(found[f].getStartOffset(), found[f].getEndOffsetInclusive(), background);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serge, I've been working on the very same problem! I've got a partial workaround to share, and some ideas to take it further.

There is no way to embed hidden text in Google Docs, as eloquently stated by Gill on the [old forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/P3jGVx-CNl8). If there was, your mailmerge would be trivial!

How about making your tags or "cookies" (almost) invisible, though? Below is a scriplet that adds a "cloaking" function to a document. It has extras as well; it queries the user for text to cloak, then searches for all instances of that text and cloaks them. The idea I settled on was to make the text as small as possible (fontsize 0) and to match the foreground color to the background color.

```
// in menu:       .addItem('Text Cloaking', 'cloakOn')

/**
 * Find all matches of target text in current document, and cloak them.
 * At this time, that consists of making the text tiny, but still visible.
 * This is an experiment - my hope was to find a way to implement something
 * like document variables, placeholders that would not be forgotten, so
 * that values could be changed, or even dynamic.
 *
 * @param {String} target     (Optional) The text or regex to search for. 
 *                            See Body.findText() for details.
 * @param {String} background (Optional) The desired highlight color.
 *                            A default orange is provided.
 */
function cloakOn(target) {
  // If no search parameter was provided, ask for one
  if (arguments.length == 0) {
    var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
    var result = ui.prompt('Text Cloaking',
      'Enter text to cloak:', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    // Exit if user hit Cancel.
    if (result.getSelectedButton() !== ui.Button.OK) return;
    // else
    target = result.getResponseText();
  }
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var bodyElement = doc.getBody();
  var searchResult = bodyElement.findText(target);

  while (searchResult !== null) {
    var thisElement = searchResult.getElement();
    var thisElementText = thisElement.asText();

    //Logger.log(url);
    thisElementText.setFontSize(searchResult.getStartOffset(), searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),0);
    var background = thisElementText.getBackgroundColor(searchResult.getStartOffset()) || "#ffffff";
    thisElementText.setForegroundColor(searchResult.getStartOffset(), searchResult.getEndOffsetInclusive(),
                                       background);

    // search for next match
    searchResult = bodyElement.findText(target, searchResult);
  }
}
```

To make use of this in the text-replacement operation, the replacement text would carry a cloaked tag (as you're doing). I think you'd want to make your tags as short as possible, so that the white space they occupy in the final document is very small - I was playing with using a series of unicode characters as digits, to give a large range of 2-digit 'numbers' that would be unlikely to show up in any other context.

Comment: Brilliant idea :-) I didn't think of hiding the fields this way... I'm going to implement that immediately, thanks.